# How to store multiple value in SharedPreferences in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

how can i store multiple values in my SharedPreferences ? i want to make a list of favourite items in my application where user can store their favourite item from another section of app
for ex:
[image]

When Click on favourite(heart) button value should be store in SharedPreferences..

and then store values show in favourite screen
[image]

Comment: You might, but I personally don't recommend it, you should use SharedPreferences for some security/sensitive details (tokens, pass, etc). IMO, use [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), I find it a better solution than using any secure storage packages for these purposes. Cheers.

Comment: sqflite is offline database?i don't knOW anything about sqflite

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `hive` (https://pub.dev/packages/hive). It's a more lightweight database than `sqflite`, and also the package works on all platforms while `sqflite` only works on Android, iOS and MacOS.

Comment: Yeah, it's an offline database, you just add it as a package to your .yaml file and follow the examples for it. Or as my Balkan friend @Andrej suggested, you can use `hive` also, they both have the same purpose, both have their differences so you can read the documentation for both and make your choosing.

Comment: @GrandMagus On point! Cheers brate... :)